# Loop through set of objects with MAP and add new element in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5 app I have a list of @rides

```
@rides = Ride.all
```

I know that I can use

@rides.map to loop through all objects and modify their elements. But can I also add a new one? This new one I want to create based on a rule using the current_user. That's why I do not want to do it in the model.

I would want to do something like:

```
@rides.map do |ride|
  ride.a = '123'
end
```

where 'a' is not a column or anything in the object. I want to add it to each ride in my @rides object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `attr_accessor :a` to `Ride` model and add value in a controller

```
@rides.each do |ride|
  ride.a = '123'
end
```